# How to get only top 3 values of an array in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which look like this

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "f3187b40cacac21f88c60"
  },
  "recipeId": "3da8f8ddfa600294b278d",
  "dish": "abc",
  
  "Profile": {
    "Tag": [
      {
        "Tag": "X",
        "ratios": 5.9751602852
      },
      {
        "Tag": "Y",
        "ratios": 53.9308283909
      },
      {
        "Tag": "Z",
        "ratios": 12.3244466278
      },
      {
        "Tag": "A",
        "ratios": 13.1145449121
      },
      {
        "Tag": "B",
        "ratios": 1.3848693181
      },
      {
        "Tag": "C",
        "ratios": 1.2996209903
      }
```

In the output of aggregation I want recipeId,dish and top3 tags along with its ratios.I am trying to create a table of recipeId , dish , tags and ratios in Redash.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- `$sortArray` is added in MongoDB 5.2
- the bellow works with unwind because probably you dont have the 5.2 version
- unwind and sort, group back, and finally take the first 3 only with `$slice`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=628b94ec853f039c69b0f8f9)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind": "$Profile.Tag"}, 
 {"$sort": {"Profile.Tag.ratios": -1}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": "$_id",
    "recipeId": {"$first": "$recipeId"},
    "dish": {"$first": "$dish"},
    "Tag": {"$push": "$Profile.Tag"}}},
 {"$set": {"Profile": {"Tag": {"$slice": ["$Tag", 3]}},
  "Tag": "$$REMOVE"}}])
```